# Unable to compile Typescript file, file is not a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am facing a problem in compiling my `.ts` file when I am trying to import a class.

Here is my `BookController.ts` file which I am trying to import into the `BookRoute.ts` file,

```
import { Request } from 'express';
import { BookService } from '../services/BookService';

export class BookController{
    private bookService: BookService = new BookService();

    public getAllBooks() {
        this.bookService.getAllBooks();
    }

    public createBook(req: Request) {
        this.bookService.createBook(req);
    }
}
```

The `BookRoute.ts` is given below, it throws the error at `line 2` of this file where I am trying to `import` my `BookController.ts`

```
import { Application } from 'express';
import { BookController } from '../controllers/BookController';

export class BookRoute {
    private bookController: BookController = new BookController();

    public route(app: Application) {
        app.route('/').get(this.bookController.getAllBooks);

        app.route('/addBook').post(this.bookController.createBook);
    }
}
```

The error is is throwing is,

```
 return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/routes/BookRoute.ts:2:32 - error TS2306: File '/home/toorja/workspace/Book-Post-Service/src/controllers/BookController.ts' is not a module.

2 import { BookController } from '../controllers/BookController';
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    at createTSError (/home/toorja/workspace/Book-Post-Service/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:500:12)
    at reportTSError (/home/toorja/workspace/Book-Post-Service/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:504:19)
    at getOutput (/home/toorja/workspace/Book-Post-Service/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:739:36)
    at Object.compile (/home/toorja/workspace/Book-Post-Service/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:955:32)
    at Module.m._compile (/home/toorja/workspace/Book-Post-Service/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1043:43)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/home/toorja/workspace/Book-Post-Service/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1046:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:941:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:782:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:19)
```

My `tsconfig.json` is like this,

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",                         
    "module": "commonjs", 
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true, 
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true, 
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

My `devDependencies`,

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/bluebird": "^3.5.32",
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.7",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.8",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "@types/mysql2": "github:types/mysql2",
    "@types/node": "^14.11.8",
    "@types/sequelize": "^4.28.9",
    "@types/validator": "^13.1.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "class-validator": "^0.12.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "sequelize": "^6.3.5",
    "sequelize-typescript": "^1.1.0",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mysql2": "^2.2.5"
  }
```

I have changed the `tsconfig.json` file according to some of the questions that I searched in SO regarding similar issue, but the changes I made did not solve my problem. It is all the same.

I tried stopping `nodemon` and rerunning `npm run dev`, but of no result.

I am using a 64 bit Kali Linux machine. Thanks for your time.